# Structure constructor with private component

Tags: fortran, fortran2008

I have defined a structure with a private component in following example:

```
module mtypes
    implicit none

    type mytype
        integer, private :: nr
    end type

end module mtypes

program main

    use mtypes
    type(mytype) :: t1

    t1 = mytype(1)
    print *, t1

end program main
```

The structure constructor is called with 1 as an argument. For my understanding this should not be possible, because `nr` is private. However, this is compiled by `Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler XE 14.0.5.239 [IA-32]`, but not with `gfortran 4.9.3` using `cygwin`. Moreover the `print` statement shows the value of `nr` in the output. Is it valid `Fortran` to define a structure with a private component in this way using the latest standard? Or is this a bug of the intel compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the draft of Fortran 2008, implicit (that is, those that comes from the derived type definition) structure constructors are detailed in 4.5.10.  One constraint given there is

> The type name and all components of the type for which a component-spec appears shall be accessible in the scoping unit containing the structure constructor.

As the component `nr` is not accessible in the main program this constraint is violated by having `nr` as a component-spec.  Using this implicit structure constructor in the module would be fine, as would having default initialization for the private component.

nagfor also complains about your code example for this reason.

On the `print` statement, this is clearly not valid, and ifort 15 complains about that.  For `t1` to appear in an output list you must use a define output procedure.